# Select information from table from many bases

Tags: c#, sql, t-sql

How can I select information from tables from many bases in one result. My idea is to put them in DataTable and show them in DataGrid.

Here is query:

```
exec sp_msforeachdb 'use ?; IF ''?'' <> ''master'' AND ''?'' <> ''model'' AND ''?'' <> ''msdb'' AND ''?'' <> ''tempdb'' AND ''?'' <> ''addresses'' AND ''?'' <> ''ikamebeldizain'' AND ''?'' <> ''new2'' AND ''?'' <> ''sample'' AND ''?'' <> ''sitedatabase'' AND ''?'' <> ''StudentsTeachersTest'' AND ''?'' <> ''MicroinvestDatabasesCatalog'' select * from dbo.system;'
```

When I try with this query in dataGrid i have just one line (first result).

Comment: How are you filling the datatable in c#?

Comment: Also, do you only get one row when you execute this in SSMS?

Comment: You cannot produce a single result set with `sp_msforeachdb`. You'd need a custom query that loops over `select * from sys.databases`, inserts in a temp table, then selects that temp table at the end. (Well, you can also insert in a temp table with `sp_msforeachdb`, but... if you can, just write something yourself, this thing is undocumented for a reason.)

Comment: Many `bases` you mean multiple databases on the same server?

Comment: sp_msforeachdb returns a resultset for each database. Note from [BOL](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/905keexk(v=vs.110).aspx): "When handling batch SQL statements that return multiple results, the implementation of Fill and FillSchema for a .NET Framework data provider retrieves schema information for only the first result."

Comment: @CDove, yep 223 results.

Comment: Can someone Help with creating query?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I make a solution:

```
    DECLARE @db_id AS int 
    DECLARE @db_name AS sysname
 CREATE TABLE ##CompatibleDatabases
    (       
      Name sysname, 
      CompanyName nvarchar(255),
      ProductID smallint,
      [Version] nvarchar(20),
      [Code] int
    )

    SET ROWCOUNT 0
    SELECT  dbid AS [ID], Name AS [Name] INTO #AllDatabases FROM master..sysdatabases
        SET ROWCOUNT 1
    SELECT @db_id = [ID] FROM #AllDatabases
        WHILE @@rowcount <> 0
    BEGIN

        SET ROWCOUNT 0

        BEGIN TRY

            SET @db_name = db_name(@db_id)

            EXEC ('IF (
                EXISTS ( SELECT * FROM [' + @db_name + '].INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES WHERE TABLE_NAME=''System'') AND
                EXISTS ( SELECT * FROM [' + @db_name + '].INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS WHERE TABLE_NAME=''System'' AND COLUMN_NAME=''ProductID'' ) AND
                EXISTS ( SELECT * FROM [' + @db_name + '].INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS WHERE TABLE_NAME=''System'' AND COLUMN_NAME=''Version'' ) 
            )
            BEGIN
                DECLARE @insertStatement nvarchar(500)

                IF (EXISTS ( SELECT * FROM [' + @db_name + '].INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS WHERE TABLE_NAME=''System'' AND COLUMN_NAME=''CompanyName'' ) )
                    SET @insertStatement=''INSERT INTO ##CompatibleDatabases SELECT ''''' + @db_name + ''''' AS Name, CompanyName, ProductID, [Version], [Code] FROM [' + @db_name + '].dbo.System''
                ELSE
                    SET @insertStatement=''INSERT INTO ##CompatibleDatabases SELECT ''''' + @db_name + ''''' AS Name,''''' + @db_name + ''''' AS CompanyName, ProductID, [Version], NULL AS Code FROM [' + @db_name + '].dbo.System''

                EXEC(@insertStatement) 
            END')

        END TRY

        BEGIN CATCH

        END CATCH

        DELETE #AllDatabases WHERE [ID] = @db_id

        SET ROWCOUNT 1
        SELECT @db_id = [ID] FROM #AllDatabases 
    END

    SET ROWCOUNT 0
    select * from ##CompatibleDatabases

    DROP TABLE #AllDatabases
    DROP TABLE ##CompatibleDatabases
```

Answer (score 2):

To append multiple result sets in SQL, you need to have identical results structure (ie: the same columns are returned in the same order) and to tell SQL to bolt them together with a `union all` (Using just `union` will remove duplicate rows).  To do this across different databases, assuming they are on the same server you can just reference the database in your query:

```
select *
from Database1.dbo.system
union all
select *
from Database2.dbo.system
```

If you are trying to do this across a dynamic set of databases, you will only be able to do this with dynamic SQL, which will output the above statement based on a list of databases provided earlier in the script, which you can then execute.